# Inconsistency in STL container adapters

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

STL [queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/queue/) has `front()` and `back()` methods, but [stack](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/stack/) has only `top()`, but not `bottom()`. Why is that so?

Comment: Pedantic note, `queue` and `stack` are not containers.

Comment: Because it's a stack. It's intentionally limited to last-in, first-out access, because that's how a stack is defined. A queue is first-in, first-out, so you *need* access to both ends.

Comment: You could just as easily add that `list` has push_back and push_front, but `vector` has push_back only. In this case the reason is the efficiency with which you can implement the operation.

Comment: @jahhaj: That's different – `list` and `vector` are containers, and the operations they support depend on the algorithmic complexity necessary for the operations. On the other hand, `queue` and `stack` are container adaptors – they are designed to have a very limited interface.

Comment: I guess the question is "why does queue have a `back()` method and no method that allows you to remove that element from the back".

Comment: @juanchopanza: thanks for the pedantic note = )
I know stack is LIFO and queue is FIFO, and it's logical for stack to have just `top()`. However, although internally we need to be able to access to the back of queue to add a new item, I feel like it isn't a good idea to expose it in interface.

Answer (score 8):

The only reason for `stack` is to prohibit access to the wrapped container except as a stack, i.e. accessing the top only. If you want a container that can be used as a stack but which is not restricted to only working as a stack, then you can use a different sequence container, such as a raw `vector`.

Similarly, the only reason for `queue` is to prohibit access to the wrapped container except as a queue, i.e. accessing the front and back. If you want a container that can be used as a queue but which is not restricted to only working as a queue, then you can use a different sequence container, such as a raw `vector`.

Answer (score 2):

A queue typically represents a first in first out (FIFO) buffer. You can access both ends. One end has the most recent item and the other end has the oldest item. You might want to access the most recent item from the code that is adding elements to the queue and the oldest item from code that processes items from the queue.

A stack typically represents a last in first out (LIFO) buffer. You can only access one end, which is the most recent item added to the stack. So there only needs to be a top(), and no bottom().